# Cell Comparison in Word Table's Text, Then Export Data

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-word

**SEE ANSWER BELOW**
**EDIT:**  Thanks to the answer below, I was able to go down the path of debugging and get something to work properly.  I'm now at a point that I can do this on my own with the following main function.  Thankfully there is no superfluous data so regex is fine as well as just selecting the right table and taking each row as shown in this main function:

```
function Main {
    # For script modification. Like C/C++ #define preprocessor commands
    Set-Variable BLAHBLAH_NUMBER_COLUMN_NUMBER -value ([byte]1) -option Constant
    Set-Variable BLAHBLAH_TEXT_COLUMN_NUMBER -value ([byte]2) -option Constant
    Set-Variable BLAHBLAHTWO_NUMBER_COLUMN_NUMBER -value ([byte]3) -option Constant
    Set-Variable BLAHBLAHTWO_TEXT_COLUMN_NUMBER -value ([byte]4) -option Constant
    Set-Variable MOREDATABLAHBLAH_COLUMN_NUMBER -value ([byte]9) -option Constant
    Set-Variable IMPORTANT_TABLES_COLUMN_COUNT -value ([byte]9) -option Constant

    # Open up word doc with data we want
    $tempfilename = "FILENAMEGOESHERE" # For testing
    $global:filename = "$($pwd)\$tempfilename"
    Write-Host $filename # For testing
    $global:Word_Object = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $RQ_Object.Visible = $true
    $WordDocument = $Word_Object.Documents.Open($filename)

    ExcelCOMObjectGen
    HeaderGenerationWithPrompt
    HeaderFormat
    HeaderColoring
    ColumnHeadersGeneration

    # Find the important table
    $ImportantTable = $WordDocument.Tables | Where-Object{$_.Columns.Count -eq $IMPORTANT_TABLES_COLUMN_COUNT}
    Write-Host $ImportantTable.Rows.Count "rows with desired prefix"


    ### THIS BLOCK FOR LOGS FOR DEBUGGING/DEVELOPMENT ###
    ### THIS BLOCK FOR LOGS FOR DEBUGGING/DEVELOPMENT ###
    ### THIS BLOCK FOR LOGS FOR DEBUGGING/DEVELOPMENT ###    
    foreach ($row in $ImportantTable.Rows) {
        $printableTextOne = $row.Cells.Item(1).Range.Text
        $printableTextTwo = $row.Cells.Item(2).Range.Text
        $printToFileText = "$($printableTextOne): $($printableTextTwo)`n"
        $printToFileText | Add-Content 'log.txt'
    }
    ### THIS BLOCK FOR LOGS FOR DEBUGGING/DEVELOPMENT ###
    ### THIS BLOCK FOR LOGS FOR DEBUGGING/DEVELOPMENT ###
    ### THIS BLOCK FOR LOGS FOR DEBUGGING/DEVELOPMENT ###
}
```

It is writing exactly the information I need to the text document, and I just need to replace the terminating characters and then move on with adding the other documents.

---

**BEGIN ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I have scoured the internet as well as stackoverflow, working on this function for a full work day.

I am creating a powershell script to pull data from a Word table that is over 100 pages long,  If column 1 has a certain type of text, I want to export cells from that row into an excel document.

I can load the word document and generate the excel document just fine, but data is not exporting properly.

There are tables in the first few pages that are not the ~100 page table I want to parse, hence the "foreach" line.

Word Table format as follows:

A Number | A text | B Number | B text | Data1 | Data 2 | Etc. |

Attempt 1:

```
function STACKOVERFLOW {
    $WordDocument = $STACKOVERFLOW_Object.Documents.Open($STACKOVERFLOWfilename)
    $excelRowCounter = 3

    foreach ($table in $WordDocument.Tables) {

        $colcount = $table.Columns.Count
        # $rowcount = $table.Rows.Count

        # the other tables have different numbers of columns, so we can execute this
        # block if the table has the right number of columns, defined as constant at start
        if ($colcount -eq $IMPORTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_COUNT) {

            $A_NUMBER_column_TEMP = $table.cell($excelRowCounter, 1).Range.text
            $A_TEXT_column_TEMP = $table.cell($excelRowCounter, 2).Range.text
            $B_NUMBER_column_TEMP = $table.cell($excelRowCounter, 3).Range.text
            $B_TEXT_column_TEMP = $table.cell($excelRowCounter, 4).Range.text

            $worksheet.Cells.Item($excelRowCounter, 4) = "$($A_NUMBER_column_TEMP):`n$A_TEXT_column_TEMP"
            $worksheet.Cells.Item($excelRowCounter, 5) = "B Number:`n$($B_NUMBER_column_TEMP):`nB Text:`n$B_TEXT_column_TEMP"

            $excelRowCounter++
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt 1 successfully pulls from the fourth row in the Word table and puts the relevant data into the cells desired in excel.  But It's skipping rows 2-3 and 5-1,000+

Works great for a single row, and not the first entry in the table.  Or even the second. Not off-by-one.

Attempt 2:

```
function STACKOVERFLOW {
    # using $global:STACKOVERFLOW_Object or $STACKOVERFLOW_object seems to make no difference
    # same for $STACKOVERFLOWfilename
    $WordDocument = $global:STACKOVERFLOW_Object.Documents.Open($global:STACKOVERFLOWfilename)
    $excelRowCounter = 3
    $tablerows = $table.Rows.Count

    foreach ($table in $WordDocument.Tables) {
        if ($table.cell(1, 1).Range.Text -eq "text_in_(1,1)")
        {
            for (row = 2, $row -le $tablerows, $row++) {
                $tempvar = $table.cell($row, 1).Range.Text
                $worksheet.Cells.Item($excelRowCounter, 4) = "$tempvar"
                # code to enter other cells as desired here.
                excelRowCounter++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt 2 prints absolutely nothing to the excel spreadsheet.

I have also tried using -like comparison in my if statements to no avail.

I suspect that the issue in attempt 2 may be related to null terminating characters in the word table, such as how \n would cause a similar problem in other languages.

Any advice on how I can do this? The table is consistently formatted but spans 100 pages or more.  Although it doesn't seem that the column headers appearing on each page is the issue, because nothing is printing.  There are an average of about 10 rows per page.

My next attempt may be to convert the tables to Excel with example code online, then try to run these same kinds of conditions on the Excel files

Comment: This script will be used on dozens to hundreds of documents.  The script is useful because each one takes 20 hours or more by hand.

Comment: How many tables are in each document? Is there content besides the table present as well? Is there always only the one? Does it have to go into excel or is CSV acceptable?

Comment: The number of tables varies, with 8 in the current document.  The first 7 are irrelevant.  So setting Tables.Item(8) would be acceptable for this document but maybe not others.  There is text outside of the tables.

That said, it that is my only problem I'm not opposed to setting a constant for 8 for now, and adjusting as needed.

It is always the last table in the document, so perhaps I could look into a solution using the last number in foreach?

CSV is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's start with why Attempt 2 didn't work. Word messed with your text. Each cell appears to have 2 characters added to the end of the text. I worked with a sample table:

```
A Number A Text B Number B Text     Data 1            Data 2
1        Cat    10       Persian    White             Male  
2        Dog    11       Huskey     White/Grey        Male  
3        Pig    12       Potbellied Pink              Female
4        Cat    13       Tabby      White/Grey/Orange Female
5        Fish   14       Salmon     Delicious         N/A
```

I put some random text in a word doc, and another table preceding this one with 7 columns. I also setup an Excel doc with cells A1:B2 filled with text so that I had something to add data to.

I grabbed my desired table, and assigned it to a variable:

```
$MyTable = $Document.Tables | Where{$_.Columns.Count -eq 6}
```

I tried to match rows based on if `Cells.Item(2)` was in the list `'Cat','Fish'`, which should have returned 3 rows.

```
$MyTable.Rows |  ?{$_.Cells.Item(2).Range.Text -in 'Cat','Fish'}
```

It did not. So I looked more carefully at the second row, cell 2 text.

```
$Animal = $MyTable.Rows.Item(2).Cells.Item(2).Range.Text
$Animal #Returned 'Cat'
$Animal.Length #Returned 5
```

Woah, wait, 'Cat' is not 5 letters long. Ok, we have invisible characters, let's take a look:

```
$Animal.ToCharArray() | ForEach{"{0} => {1}" -f $_, ([int][char]$_)}
```

That spit back:

```
C => 67
a => 97
t => 116
 => 13
 => 7
```

A little research shows that characters 13 and 7 are added to each cell. Ok, so let's do a regex match:

```
$MyTable.Rows |  ?{$_.Cells.Item(2).Range.Text -match 'Cat|Fish'}
```

This did indeed return 3 rows of data. Ok, but a RegEx match may not be the best way to do this since it could include things you don't want. So instead let's just trim those last 2 characters off to get the original value.

```
$Tail = "{0}{1}$" -f [char][int]13, [char][int]7
$MyTable.Rows |  ?{($_.Cells.Item(2).Range.Text -replace $Tail) -in 'Cat','Fish'}
```

That also returned the desired 3 rows. Now we have something we can work with here. So then I just loop through rows with a `ForEach` loop, and for each row I go to the next available row on the Excel spreadsheet and copy values over cell by cell (copy/paste from Word to Excel turned out horrible for me, so I copied text only).

```
$MyTable.Rows |  ?{($_.Cells.Item(2).Range.Text -replace $Tail) -in 'Cat','Fish'} | %{
    $NextRow = $WB.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(($WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1), 1).EntireRow
    For($i=1;$i -le $_.Range.Columns.Count;$i++){
        $NextRow.Cells.Item($i).value2 = $_.Cells.Item($i).Range.Text -replace $Tail
    }
}
```

This resulted in the desired rows being added to the Excel sheet.

As for why Attempt 1 only copied the fourth row, it should have copied only the third row, since `$excelRowCounter = 3`. It only copied 1 thing because you only looped through tables, not through each row on each table. This probably would have worked fine if you had done it as:

```
    if ($colcount -eq $IMPORTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_COUNT) {
    For($i = 2; $i -le $Table.Rows.Range.Columns.Count; $i++){
        $A_NUMBER_column_TEMP = $table.cell($excelRowCounter, 1).Range.text
        $A_TEXT_column_TEMP = $table.cell($excelRowCounter, 2).Range.text
        $B_NUMBER_column_TEMP = $table.cell($excelRowCounter, 3).Range.text
        $B_TEXT_column_TEMP = $table.cell($excelRowCounter, 4).Range.text

        $worksheet.Cells.Item($excelRowCounter, 4) = "$($A_NUMBER_column_TEMP):`n$A_TEXT_column_TEMP"
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($excelRowCounter, 5) = "B Number:`n$($B_NUMBER_column_TEMP):`nB Text:`n$B_TEXT_column_TEMP"

        $excelRowCounter++
    }
    }
```

That would skip the first row (you can adjust that by changing the `2` in `$i = 2`), and would copy everything over as you intended.

Comment: Wow! That is an incredibly detailed answer with great explanation.  I will be sure to re-attack the problem considering your comments as soon as possible and let you know the results.  Seems my suspicion of end characters was a good start.

Comment: As for "the fourth row," I was counting the headers as the first row, it seems powershell may not (or I am thinking incorrectly).  It was copying the third A_Number row.

Comment: This set me on the path to solving the problem and I learned a good amount from your answer.  It also showed me some tricks in using the terminal live for testing my variables and logic. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm glad you took the time to learn the tactics. Happy to help.